# Two Dictionary Compare in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'a': '14591', 'b': '14590', 'c': '14590', 'd': '14590', 'e': '14590'}   
dict2 = {"k": '0', "l": '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '6', 'e': '7'}

dict3 = {'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '6', 'e': '7'}
```

I couldn't get what I need, so I need your help. `dict1` and `dict2` are output of my work. I need compare them to take `dict3` if keys of `dict1` are in `dict2`.

Comment: `{i:dict2[i] for i in set(dict1.keys()).intersection(dict2.keys())}`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conditional dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1}
{'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '6', 'e': '7'}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Next time please post your existing attempt (i.e. existing code) so that we can comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
dict1 = {'a': '14591', 'b': '14590', 'c': '14590', 'd': '14590', 'e': '14590'}

dict2 = {"k": '0', "l": '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '6', 'e': '7'}
dict_3 = {}

for key_1, val_1 in dict1.items():
    if key_1 in dict2:
        dict_3[key_1] = dict2[key_1]
print(dict_3)
```

Output:

```
{'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '6', 'e': '7'}
```

Comment: You don't need `val_1`. Also you can omit `.keys()` in the `if` clause.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you for your comment about `. keys ()` can really be omitted(I just wanted to write as much detail as possible). As for `val_1`, I will say that the dictionary will then record the values of the dictionary `dict1`, and you need `dict2`

Comment: Sorry, I meant you are not using `val_1` anywhere in your code.